# debug Navigation stack, xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

My little app was working, then I tried to change the navigation a little and now it crashes at

```
await Navigation.PopAsync();
```

I wonder if there is a way to be able to see the navigation stack, to know what would be expected when i do the Pop. I use PushAsync to get to this page, but since it crash here, I maybe screwed up somewhere else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have access to the Navigation Stack by calling Navigation.NavigationStack. If you want to know what is in there you could find the Type of each object within it.